# Error in downloading an audio file form server synchronously

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsoperationqueue, nsblockoperation

I am using a `NSBlockOperation` in which i am trying to downlaod an audio file from server & storing it in documents directory.

```
NSBlockOperation *audioOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
//Perform doanload
 NSString *itemStoredPath = [self downloadPOIAudioByUrl:itemUrl itemName:itemName folderName:itemFolder iteInfo:cacheAudioDetails];

// Update database
.....
}];


-(NSString *)downloadPOIAudioByUrl:(NSString *)itemUrl itemName:(NSString *)itemName folderName:(NSString *)folderName iteInfo:(CacheAudioDetails *)itemInfo {
    // Get the url for video upload
    NSURL *audioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[itemUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // Set the response parameter
    NSURLResponse *serverResponce = nil;
    // Set the error parameter
    NSError *error = nil;
    // Create a request & set the time out interval for 1 min.
    //NSURLRequest *videoRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLRequest *audioRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:audioUrl];
    // Set the connection
    NSData *audioData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:audioRequest returningResponse:&serverResponce error:&error];
    if (error == nil && audioData != nil) {
      // Data Found
      // Store in directory & return the path to store in database
      return audioPath;
    }
 return nil;
}
```

I have made a synchronous call to downlaod an audio file. But it is taking too much time & after long time it returns zero bytes of NSData.I thought it was due to my timed out request for 60 sec. Then i removed the time out request but still the problem remains as it is. My query is

1. Time out is related to server connection & not to fetching data from server
2. What should be the reason of Zero bytes responce from server.

Comment: Can your app really connect to your server?

Comment: may I ask why do you want to download it in synchronous call?

Comment: Methods which take a pointer to a NSError object pointer, always indicate a possible error through the return value. That means, test the return value if you got an error. Never check the error object parameter if this is nil or not to figure whether you got an error. You can use the error parameter only after the method indicated an error through the return value.

Comment: When dealing with networking, you also should use asynchronous style. The synchronous _convenient_ network request methods are solely meant for toy apps and demonstration purposes.